# Jquery value change event

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some code,when I click the button it show me some message.It works on IE good,but dont works on ff or chrome,somebody tell why?Sorry for my poor english.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <title> New Document </title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(function(){
            $("#test").bind("input propertychange",function(){
                alert("abc");
            });
        });
        function ff() 
                { 
                document.getElementById('test').value=Math.random(); 

    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <input id="test"></input>
    <input id='btn' value="tt" type="button" onclick="ff()" /> 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: what message does it show you ? Also, there is a syntax error in your code. Not sure how it works on IE

Comment: sorry my mistake,I lost a '}' above the '</script>'

Comment: When I click the button,I hope the page give me alert!@karthikr

Comment: check my answer to the question. I have comments in the code for the changes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some errors in the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <title> New Document </title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    $(function () {
        $('#btn').on('click', function () {
            $('#test').val(Math.random());
            $('#test').trigger('change');
        }); //missing ending }
        $('#test').bind("change paste keyup", function () { // change to a proper listener 
            alert("abc");
        });
    });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <input id="test" type="text" value="" />
    <!--             ^ Specify a "type" -->    
    <input id='btn' value="tt" type="button" /> 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks to tell me the bugs,but it's dosent work.I hope that the page show me "abc" when I click the ff button each time.

Comment: you are showing the alert button when you enter some data in the input box. If you want the alert on click, then you need to add the alert in the ff method.

Comment: If I enter something in the input box,it do show me the alert,but if I change the input value by the function ff,it dosent work.I want to know why.In fact I hope it show me the alert when I change the value of input by the function each time.

Comment: dont use the function `ff`  . Use Jquery consistently.

Answer (score 1):

First off, you're missing the closing bracket for the ff function. Secondly the event you should be listening for on the input field is the "change" event, that too only fires off when the text field has focus and you change its value and then click elsewhere in the document (i.e. it loses focus or is blurred) then the change event is fired.

What you can do instead is either listen for other events such as keyup etc. or trigger a custom change event. Here's the modified/corrected code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <title> New Document </title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script>    
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
        $('#test').on('change', function() {
            alert("abc");
        });

        $('#btn').on('click', function() {
            $('#test').val(Math.random()).trigger('change');
        });
    });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <input id="test" value="" />
    <input id="btn" value="tt" type="button" /> 

</body>
</html>
```

And try to keep away from inline javascript calls such as "onclick= ..." in HTML. Whole point is to separate JS, CSS and HTML.