# jQuery, how to capture when text input has changed as a result of another event

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a text input that is updated as a result of a button event. I would like to detect when the value in the text input has changed. See the example below:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script  type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('#text').bind("input change paste", function(){
      console.log("text changed");
      // do something
   });

   $('#click').click (function(){
      $('#text').val('something');
   });
});
</script>

<body>
   <input id='text' type='text'>
   <input id='click' type='button' value='click'>
</body>
```

Later on, that button will trigger a calender so the user select a date/time which will update the text input. Since the calender is part of a library we I don't want to change it. I would like to detect when the text field gets a new value.

thanks!

Comment: Code seems to work. What is the problem you are having? [jsFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/hDnVA/)

Comment: Are you asking how to detect if the value of `#text` changes whenever something calls `$('#text').val('sometext')` on it? In that case, you can trigger a change event by calling `$('#text').val('something').change()` from your click handler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the date/time picker library you are using doesn't raise any sort of `change` or `input` event, the only way to reliable tell if the value has changed is to watch with a timer and raise the change event yourself. The following is one way to do this:

```
// check for changes every 100 ms
setInterval(function() {
    var lastVal = $('#text').data('last-value');
    if (typeof lastVal === 'undefined') {
        lastVal = $('#text').val();
        $('#text').data('last-value', lastVal);
    }

    if (lastVal !== $('#text').val()) {
        $('#text').change(); // trigger the change event
    }
}, 100);

// setup your change handler 
$('#text').on("input change paste", function() {
    // before doing anything else, set the last-value data property
    $('#text').data('last-value', $('#text').val());

    // do something ...
    console.log('changed!');
});

// now programmitically updating the $('#text') element will result 
// in your change handler being triggered
$('#click').click (function(){
    $('#text').val('something');
});
```

Answer (score 3):

I think what you're referring to is

```
$("#text").on("change", function(){});
```

take a look at this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17006470/jquery-value-change-event?rq=1)

Comment: Even though `.on()` is the preferred way to attach event handlers, the code that the OP posted using `.bind()` works. I think the OP is asking how to tell if `#text` changes when updated using `.val()`. Using `on()` instead of `bind()` doesn't functionally change anything.

Comment: Divey is right. I would like to know when input is modified as result of .val()

Comment: @zakiya.tamimi is it an option to modify the code that is calling `val()`? In that case, you can just call `change()` after calling `val()` like so: `$('#text').val('something').change()`.

Comment: when the button is clicked a calender will render, the user can select a date/time. At that point, the text field will be updated. User can as well change date/time in text directly.

Comment: Divey, I understand your .change() hack. However, this solution requires modifying a library. Later if a new version of the library is released, my page will break.